# vs code таймаут дебаггера python attach process в удаленном docker-контейнере

Tags: python, docker, visual-studio-code, отладка, remote-debugging

Необходимо отладить сервер gunicorn в удаленном docker-контейнере

Действую следующим образом:

1. Создал docker-контекст для работы с контейнерами по ssh
2. В расширении "Docker" для VS Code получил список контейнеров и к нужному выбрал `Attach VS Code`
3. Контейнер загрузился в окне VS Code
4. Установил `apt-get update && apt-get install gdb`
5. Установил расширение Python для VS Code в контейнере
6. Создал `launch.json`:

```json
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python Debugger: Attach using Process Id",
            "type": "debugpy",
            "request": "attach",
            "processId": "${command:pickProcess}",
            "logToFile": true
        }
    ]
}
```

7. Попробовал запустить отладчик, выбирал разные процессы gunicorn

Однако запустить отладку не удалось по причине **Timeout waiting for debug server to connect**

Полез смотреть лог: `/root/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-python.debugpy-2024.0.0-linux-x64/debugpy.adapter-36535.log`

В нем отобразилось две ошибки

**Первая:**

```
I+00000.645: Injector[PID=1] output: Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".

I+00000.646: Injector[PID=1] output: 0x00007faa2c528724 in __GI_getdomainname (name=0x4 <error: Cannot access memory at address 0x4>, len=140733028513184) at ./misc/getdomain.c:41

I+00000.646: Injector[PID=1] output: 41 ./misc/getdomain.c: No such file or directory.
```

**Вторая (не уверен, что она важна, но пусть будет):**

```
I+00002.036: Injector[PID=1] output: 0x00007faa2c4b4d3c in __pthread_kill_implementation (threadid=1, signo=1, no_tid=6) at ./nptl/pthread_kill.c:29

I+00002.036: Injector[PID=1] output: 29 ./nptl/pthread_kill.c: No such file or directory.
```

Погуглил про файл `./misc/getdomain.c`, он относится к пакету `glibc`, который, как я понял, ставится вместе с `apt-get install libc-bin`, однако в контейнере уже этот пакет установлен последней версии

Пробовал также `find / -name 'getdomain'` - файлов не нашел нигде

Что это может быть за проблема?